# CMS like toolkit for editing div-content by user

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I hope this question is not too general but I guess this is a question which often comes to peoples mind:
We all know the advantages of a CMS... The user can edit and write content, upload pictures etc.

But in some cases the customer just wants a little area (div) where he can update some text or something, and no one would built up a complete CMS-Site for that (eg `Drupal` or `Wordpress`).

My idea was to make a `.txt` file and have a rich-text editor html page, where everything the user types in writes into the `.txt` with `POST` and this will be read by

```
 echo file_get_contents('example.txt');
```

works good so far. But my php is not as good, that I know how to do this with pictures.

So does anyone know something like a "little CMS like" toolkit which you can use for that. Hope you get my point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it *as simple as possible* you could:

**Upload**

- create an extra page where the user can upload images or
- allow upload of images through FTP into a fixed directory

The first one gives you some extra tasks like checking for duplicate file names and to ensure that only images are uploaded. The second one has the risk that the user might upload executable files and crashes everything.

**WYSIWYG editor**

- enable images in your editor

I think most editors, like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.com) have the possibility built-in or through a plug-in to select and insert images into the text. You can define a directory from where the user can choose the image files. That would be the directory chosen for your uploads.